# Magento 2 : Form Ui Component doesn't submit field in the html content

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I built a ui component form and it's a compilation of `<field>` tag and `<htmlContent>` tag. This is the `htmlContent` :

```
<htmlContent name="resource">
    <block class="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Package\Role\Tree" name="package_form.resources_access.resource_tree"/>
</htmlContent>
```

I loaded a template inside the block `Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Package\Role\Tree` and created some dynamic input text fields in the template.

The problem is my input text field inside `htmlContent` didn't submit with other `<field>`
Did I miss something when I was creating the `htmlContent`?

Comment: You inject this element in witch component, you d ont have any error in logs?

Comment: I try it on my local,It is working

Answer (score 6):

I found my answer by myself. I need to add `data-form-part="form-name"` to every `input` or `select` in the `htmlContent`. Then my data can be submitted with other `<field>` tag