# Custom ui_component form fieldset not submitting

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form, fieldsets

I created a custom fieldset for a ui_component form to add custom input structures. The problem is, that the inputs are not included in the POST values.

[image]

The input you see is just a simple  element in the fieldset.phtml you see in the Block code. It has a custom name "test_input_data". I implemented the fieldset similar to the conditions fieldsets on sales rules. The form namespance is **shipping_rule_form**.

```
<fieldset name="conditions" sortOrder="20">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Conditions</label>
    </settings>
    <container name="conditions_apply_to" sortOrder="10">
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <block name="conditions_apply_to" class="Company\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\ShippingRule\Edit\Tab\Conditions" />
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

In the Block i am adding the fieldset like this:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_shipping_rule');
    $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset', $formName = 'shipping_rule_form')
{
    if (!$model) {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        $model = $this->_ruleFactory->create();
        $model->load($id);
    }
    $conditionsFieldSetId = 'shipping_rule_form_conditions';

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
    $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
        'Remklov_ShippingRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
    )->setFieldSetId(
        $conditionsFieldSetId
    );

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        $fieldsetId,
        [
            'legend' => __(
                'Apply the rule only to the products matched by the rule, if following conditions are met.'
            )
        ]
    )->setRule(
        $model
    )->setRenderer(
        $renderer
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'conditions',
        'text',
        [
            'name'           => 'conditions',
            'label'          => __('Conditions'),
            'title'          => __('Conditions'),
            'required'       => true,
            'data-form-part' => $formName
        ]
    );

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    return $form;
}
```

When i do a print_r() on the getParams() in the Save-Controller, it just returns the data of the corresponding model, but not the custom input value. I also tried to add the conditions exactly like in the **sales_rule_form.xml**, but still nothing is posted.

I could not find out how the submit logic works here and where i maybe missed or need to add logic.

Comment: I also tried a very simple approach like mentioned here, but the input was still not posted. https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/3107-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this post: [Magento 2 : Form Ui Component doesn't submit field in the html content](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238520/magento-2-form-ui-component-doesnt-submit-field-in-the-html-content)

I needed to add the **data-form-part="shipping_rule_form"** to all the inputs.